# JHipster import-jdl not generating swagger

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

Is it possible to generate the swagger api.yaml from JDL?

I've created and app with swagger addon and then imported entities from jdl but the swagger api.yaml is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That specific api.yml is intended for JHipster's [API First Development](http://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/) feature.

JHipster comes configured with [Springfox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#introduction), which automatically generates the Swagger docs based on the project's code. You can access the app's Swagger config after starting the app at http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs.  It is in JSON format by default, if you need YAML you can upload it to the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/)

You can also view the docs in a built-in SwaggerUI at http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/docs, normally located under the Administration navbar menu.